# IronPython Pip Fails to Install in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, pip, ironpython

So I get this `pip.log` output whenever I try to "download and install pip package manager" through Visual Studio:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\pip_downloader.py run on 05/21/16 23:53:23
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking setuptools
  URLs to search for versions for setuptools:
  Skipping link c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7 (from -f); not a file
  Skipping link file:///c:/users/shyyguy/appdata/local/temp/tmpllj1o7/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl; wrong project name (not setuptools)
  Found link file:///c:/users/shyyguy/appdata/local/temp/tmpllj1o7/setuptools-3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl, version: 3.6
  Local files found: c:/users/shyyguy/appdata/local/temp/tmpllj1o7/setuptools-3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking pip
  URLs to search for versions for pip:
  Found link file:///c:/users/shyyguy/appdata/local/temp/tmpllj1o7/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl, version: 1.5.6
  Skipping link file:///c:/users/shyyguy/appdata/local/temp/tmpllj1o7/setuptools-3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl; wrong project name (not pip)
  Local files found: c:/users/shyyguy/appdata/local/temp/tmpllj1o7/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_ShyyGuy...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req.py", line 1441, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req.py", line 675, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    move_wheel_files(
  File "c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\users\shyyguy\appdata\local\temp\tmpllj1o7\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\wheel.py", line 209, in clobber
    shutil.copy2(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\shutil.py", line 127, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\easy_install.py' is denied. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\easy_install.py' is denied.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

   at Microsoft.Scripting.PlatformAdaptationLayer.OpenInputFileStream(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonFile.__init__(CodeContext context, String name, String mode, Int32 buffering)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(Object value)

   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.HandleException(InterpretedFrame frame, Exception exception)

   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)

   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget3(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)

   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)

   at IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding`2.SelfTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object target, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)

   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

I'm just trying to set it up, but it's proving pretty difficult with quite a few obstacles.

Comment: Are you running the install logged into a user account with system administrator privileges? It looks like it's failing because of an access failure due to insufficient  privileges.

Comment: @martineau, I am on an administrator account, though I just tried launching VS as an adminstrator and it looks like it was successful! Thank you